# Category and subcateory in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to build a Category and Subcategory feature in MEAN application.

I have a model for ProductCategoryModel.js like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var productCategorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title:{ type:String, required:true },
    slug:{ type:String, required:true },
    status:{ type:Number, required:true, default:1},
    description:{ type:String, required:true },
    post_type:{type:String, default:'product_catgory'},
    parentID:{ type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'ProductCategory', default:null},
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('ProductCategory', productCategorySchema);
```

Product category controller

```
adminApp.controller('ProductCategoryModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, productcategory, $http, $uibModalInstance) {

$scope.productCatList =  [];    
return $http.get('/api/product-category/parent-cat-list')
      .then(function (result) {
        $scope.productCatList =  result.data;
      });

});
```

product category form

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : productCategoryForm.parentID.$invalid && !productCategoryForm.parentID.$pristine }">
 <label>Parent Category</label>
<select name="parentID" class="form-control" id="parentID" ng-model="productcategory.parentID">
    <option ng-repeat="category in productCatList" value="{{category._id}}">
    {{category.title}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Now my issue is I want to show sub categories of selected parent category in new dropdown, How I can do this,I think there should a new dropdown and update its content when change parent category dropdown.

And second issue is this line of code not returning me Parent categories where parentID=null, It return me list of all categories.

```
return Promise.denodeify(Models.ProductCategoryModel.find.bind(Models.ProductCategoryModel))({ parentID: null })
    .then(function (results) {
      return results;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
adminApp.controller('ProductCategoryModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, productcategory, $http, $uibModalInstance) {
        $scope.productCatList =  [];
        return $http.get('/api/product-category/parent-cat-list')
                    .then(function (result) {
                          $scope.productCatList =  result.data;
                      });

        $scope.$watch('productcategory.parentID', function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
              if(newValue != oldValue){
                    $http.get('/api/product-category/' + $scope.productcategory.parentID)
                         .then(function (result) {
                                $scope.productSubCatList =  result.data;
                         });
              }
        });
  });
```

`$watch` would look for changes to the `productcategory.parentID` and then, when it changes, you can send a get request to the API to get all the categories where the `parentID` is the one specified.

On the server side, you will have to create an endpoint that returns all the categories based on the parentID field. In the request handler, you can do this:

```
Product.find({parentID: req.params.parentID}, function(err, categories){
  if(err) console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
  else if(categories) res.json(200, categories);
});
```

This might not completely give you the solution, but this is an approach that could be followed.

Comment: pls look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121872/search-in-whole-collectionmongodb-using-nodejs)