# Search in whole collection(mongodb) using nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to implement whole search feature in Mongodb collection using Nodejs.
What should I pass to `SaleModel.find()` so given value search in whole collection?

Here is what I have try so for but it only search product_name and I want to search sale_amount, sale_person, department_name too.

How I can do this?

```
SaleModel.find({'product_name': 'searched value'});
```

Schema:

```
var saleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    product_name:{ type:String, required:true},
    sale_amount:{ type:Number, required:true },
    sale_date:{ type:Date, default:Date() },
    sale_person:{ type:String, required:true }, 
    department:{ type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'department' },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('sale', saleSchema);
```

Comment: Read docs about express route, your `list` function totally mess and incorrect

Comment: Show router also, if  `Models.SaleModel` is a mongoose model, mongoose doesn't support promises awaik, only callbacks

Comment: Why do you return total count of matched data, and total data. The length of total data is itself count.

Comment: Give some reason, why close vote? are you unable to understand the question? or question is not related to programming?

Comment: Please put the code in your question back the way it was when you first posted. When you change the code you originally posted, you change the question to a new and different question rendering the answers received so far completely out of context. That is NOT how this site is supposed to work. If you need to communicate additional code, then you can add it afterwards. In this particular case, you don't need to show the code you tried as that is already covered in the answer. You can just add a comment that you tried the suggestion and explain what you observed.

Comment: I have just simple question how I can find in whole collection so there is no need to put the whole code.

Comment: Use this: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/text/

Comment: I got this: `SaleModel.find({$text: {$search: searchString}});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly write more cleaner, below sample uses [`async.parallel`](https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback), *Promise* and *Mongoose.Query*

```
function list(req) {

    // promise or callback works as well
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        // npm install async --save
        var async = require('async'); 

        // some validation can be applied
        var page = {
            skip: req.query.start || 1,
            limit: req.query.length || 25,
            text: req.query.search || ''      // <== this is new property!
        };

        // reuse Mongoose.Query with search by regex
        var Query = Models.SaleModel.find({
            product_name: new RegExp(page.text, "i")
        });

        // run without waiting until the previous function has completed
        async.parallel([
            function(){
                Query.count(callback); // <== count
            },
            function(){
                Query.skip(page.skip).limit(page.limit).exec('find', callback); // <== items
                // or the below one should also work, just don't remember
                // Query.skip(page.skip).limit(page.limit).exec(callback);
            }
        ]), function(err, results){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve({
                    count: results[0],
                    data: results[1]
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Updated, and please keep in mind, never change question drastically, you removed 1000 symbols

Comment: What about this? 
`SaleModel.find({$text: {$search: searchString}});`

Comment: This required indexing the schema, it's more robust way, but still i wanted to show the simplest way